# How to select rows until you reach a sum with slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I've the following code at the moment:

```
var test: Rep[Long] = 4234
Model.sellOrder
  .filter(_.price <= price)
  .sortBy(_.price.asc)
  .filter(order => {test -= order.amount; test < 0})
```

I want to select the rows until the total of amounts reaches 4234.

Comment: Think how would you do it in plain sql. Slick query will be mapped to sql, you can't just do things like that.

Comment: With sql this can be achieved with a running total, I guess.

Comment: This sort of query is usually done using a window function. I don't think you can do those with just Slick (at least without defining your own function). It would help knowing which RDBMS you're using. If you're using PostgreSQL then you should be able to use [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) and a `SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY price)` combined with a `WHERE sum < test` to get what you want.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL and I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments it is not possible to implement it entirely on the database since it would require support for cumulative sum. But this can be partially achieved by implementing the final filter on the JVM using collections instead on the database using the same imperative approach adopted in the question.

```
var test = 4234
db.run(Model.sellOrder
  .filter(_.price <= price)
  .sortBy(_.price.asc)
  .result) map {
    case rows => 
           rows.map(x => { test -= x; x -> test })
          .takeWhile({ case (_,x) => x > 0})
          .map({case (x,_) => x})
   }
```